# How to filter File.Delete function to certain file extensions?

Tags: c#

I use the following function in c# to delete all contents in a folder; however, I am wondering if I can add onto this function to only delete files with the file extension ".dll".

```
Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(DIRname), File.Delete);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use overloaded method `Directory.GetFiles(string,string)` topass SearchPattern as `*.dll` to get all the files with the extension of `.dll`

[Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Returns the names of files (including their paths) that match the
>   specified search pattern in the specified directory.

Try This:

```
Directory.GetFiles(DIRname,"*.dll")
```

Comment: @JimMischel, ya just forgot about that (due to a time limit).

Answer (score 0):

`File.Delete` doesn't support any wildcard.

You can use one of the two options below (uses "*.dll" wildcard, you can change it as needed).

Get all files and use Parallel.ForEach to delete them in parallel, much faster than normal loop.

```
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\mypath", "*.dll");
    Parallel.ForEach(files, (f)=> File.Delete(f));
```

Or, use the windows command shell with DEL command:

```
    Process process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = @"/C del c:\mypath\*.dll",

        }
    };
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: It's highly unlikely that deleting in parallel will be faster. The limiting factor on file deletion is file system access, and that's going to be serialized.

Comment: True, but solid state drives may give some edge. May be running a benchmark on this is a good idea :)

Comment: Again, highly unlikely. Access to the directory information is serialized, so it doesn't matter if it's spinning rust or SSD or RAM disk. The system can only delete one file at a time per logical drive.